# Google Drive Rest API in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android, google-drive-api

I have a Xamarin Android App, which takes daily backup of customer data on Google Drive using his logged in google user account. I was using Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Drive till now but it seems its now Deprecated in December 2019 and have been asked to migrate to Google Drive REST API.

A sample app is given at https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/tree/master/drive/deprecation but could not find any reference about using it with Xamarin Android.

This project has a helper file DriveServiceHelper.java which uses

com.google.api.client;
com.google.api.services;

But I am not able to find any such libraries in Xamarin Android.

Any help regarding this will of great help.

Answer (score 1):

> using his logged in google user account.

If you mean can not logging in google user account , you can refer to LuisDavidDelaCruz's answer -- [Login with google account](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/132250/login-with-google-account):

**Plugin for Xamarin.Forms**:
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.GoogleClient/1.1.0
- https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth

**Tutorials**:
- [Authenticate users Through Google with Xamarin.Auth](https://timothelariviere.com/2017/09/01/authenticate-users-through-google-with-xamarin-auth/)
- [Authenticate users Through Google with Plugin.GoogleClient](https://github.com/Pujolsluis/GoogleAuthXamarinSample)

By the way , there is a **[Google.Apis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/)** Nuget Package which contains `Google.Apis.Services` and `Google.Apis.Auth` . You also can have a look at its Source Project .(will be helpful)

Comment: Authentication and Google singin is not a problem, which can be done using GoogleApiClient but I am unable to find GoogleAccountCredential in any of above libraries.